# How can I subscribe to real-time updates of 'music.listens' for a user?

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I'm trying to use the facebook subscriptions api to get real-time updates of changes to a user's 'music.listens' connection. 
It doesn't look like this is currently possible, but I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/:

> Note that you can not subscribe to changes on all properties and connections of the User object. Connections to which you can subscribe include: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins, location, events.

So, no 'music.listens' yet.